# Get Octopus Deployment Folder at beginning of release process

Tags: octopus-deploy

I'm using an Octopus custom template with a powershell script to delete old deployments by age or by count. However, it relies on running *after* an actual deployment step, so that it can access the output variables of that step. For example,

```
DeploymentFolder:
#{Octopus.Action[Deployment Step Name].Output.Package.InstallationDirectoryPath}
```

This works great when, for example, you haven't run out of disk space. However, it doesn't work so well when disk space is low (since you didn't have this step running before) and Octopus can't deploy a new version due to the low disk space condition, thus you can't run the delete old files step. (I know one can change the Octopus parameter for what's considered too little disk space, but I'd rather not do that.) This additionally has a problem where if you want to enter a hardcoded path (say you're experiencing a temporary problem with your script and just need to delete a bunch of old deployments, but don't currently have the permissions needed to delete them manually from the server), it's too easy to accidentally leave off the final version-number-bearing folder and have the underlying script get confused.

Is there some way that I can get the deployment folder for the current environment, and combine it with my NuGet package name (and whatever other parts are in the deployment folder name), so I can work out the expected deployment folder in advance?

The actual deployment folder being used is `E:\Octopus\Applications\LifeCycle\NugetPackageName`.

I think I can get the `NugetPackageName` with `$OctopusParameters['Octopus.Action[Deployment Step Name].Package.NuGetPackageId']` (though I am not sure, as `Octopus.Action.Package.NuGetPackageId` [is listed as an "Action-Level Variable"](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/System+variables), and thus may not be available in advance of the step running. I'd be willing to hard-code the NuGet package name if I had to.

About the `LifeCycle` part, I don't know if that is actually a `LifeCycle` name. It may be a coincidence that it matches. I'm not sure. For the life of me I can't figure out where this comes from.

I also can't figure out where `E:\Octopus\Applications\` comes from, so that I can get this value automatically instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: Why aren't you just using the built in retention functionality that is offered by Lifecycles to help clean up old deployments?

Comment: We want different rules per project and different types of cleanup—per count or days or other criteria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This variable will be available at the start of the deployment:

```
$OctopusParameters['Octopus.Action[Deployment Step Name].Package.NuGetPackageId']
```

You can get `E:\Octopus\Applications\` from an environment variable called `TentacleApplications`:

```
$myRootDir = $env:TentacleApplications
```